# where python store global and local variables?

Tags: python, implementation, language-implementation

Almost same as question [Where are the local, global, static, auto, register, extern, const, volatile variables are stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684760/where-the-local-global-static-auto-register-extern-const-volatile-variabl),  the difference is this thread is asking how Python language implement this.

Comment: Which Python implementation are you asking about? CPython?

Comment: @GregS: that question is about C and Objective C, this is about Python.  Though neither question specifies an implementation, so I suppose in both cases the correct answer is 'it could be anywhere'.

Comment: I understand the question could be more elaborate - but I see no reason for it to be so heavily downvoted.  It is "legit" and the answer does not depend on the Python implementation at all.

Comment: @jsbueno: I didn't downvote, but the answer "in memory" seems to apply and that can't be what the OP is after. I'm wondering if the OP wants dynamic access to attributes, or what?

Comment: I cannot ask questions anymore :-(. I didn't intend to ask question to waste other's time and effort, the question is because I have a task to translate human read txt file to python unittest object, I want to set suite level variable, testcase level variable, so understand python's implement is good for help.

Answer (score 6):

Of all those, Python only has "local", "global" and "nonlocal" variables.

Some of those are stored in a Dictionary or dictionary like object, which usually can be explicitly addressed.

**"global"**: Actually "global" variables are global relatively to the module where they are defined - sometimes they are referred to as "module level" variables instead of globals, since most of evils of using global variables in C do not apply - since one won't have neither naming conflicts neither won't know wether a certain name came from when using a module-level global variable.

Their value is stored in the dictionary available as the  "__dict__" attribute of a module object. It is important to note that all names in a module are stored in this way - since names in Python point to any akind of object: that is, there is no distinction at the language level, of "variables", functions or classes in a module: the names for all these objects will be keys in the "__dict__" special attribute, which is accessed directly by the Language. Yes, one can insert or change the objects pointed by variables in a module at run time with the usual "setattr", or even changing the module's __dict__ directly.

**"local"**: Local variables are available fr "user code" in a dictionary returned by the "locals()" buil-in function call. This dictionary is referenced by the "f_locals" attribute of the current code frame being run. Since there are ways of retrieving the code frame of functions that called the current running code, one can retrieve values of the variables available in those functions using the f_locals attribute, although in the CPython implementation, changing a value in the f_locals dictionary won't reflect on the actuall variable values of the running code - those values are cached by the bytecode machinery.

**"nonlocal"** Variables are special references, inside a function to variables defined in an outter scope, in the case of functions (or other code, like a class body) defined inside a function. They can be retrieved in running code, by getting the func_closure attribute - which is a tuple of "cell" objects. For example, to retrieve the value of the first  nonlocal variable inside a function object, one does:_
`function.func_closure[0].cell_contents` - the values are kept separate from the variable names, which can be retrieved as `function.func_code.co_varnames`. (this naming scheme is valid for Python 2.x)

The bottom-line: Variable "values" are always kept inside objects that are compatible with Python objects and managed by the virtual machine. Some of these data can be made programmatically accessible through introspection - some of it is opaque. (For example, retrieving, through introspection, nonlocal variables from inside the function that owns them itself is a bit tricky)

Comment: Good answer. However my understanding of how locals work in CPython, is that they are stored in a C array (on the frame object), and accessed with an integer index rather than a string key. It's more that the dictionary returned by `locals()` uses cached values than the other way around.

Comment: This storage you describe is the one I refer as "cached by the bytecode machinery" in the answer above.